# Can't add shared project as reference in xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have a Xamarin solution where I have an iOS project and a shared 'services' project. Now I have to include the services project as a reference in the iOS project. But when I go to the option of adding a reference, the services project is disabled saying that the build target is incompatible:
[image]

When I checked he list of available targets, this is what I got:
[image]

FYI, this project was developed on windows machine and now it has been ported on a mac.

What should be done to make the project available as a reference?

Answer (score 1):

You cant use ordinary class library as reference in Xamarin projects. You can use **Portable class library** (PCL) libraries for common code. For PCL, you must specify the "profile" - .NET 4.5, xamarin ios and xamarin android are in several of these.